# Implementing for and while loops in R

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop, statistics

I'm trying to write code that would find the median of each column in R as a way for me to better understand for and while loops.  However, I'm not quite sure why its not working and could use some help.

For my for loop, here's what I have now

```
D=c(1:2000)
myMatrix1<-matrix(data = D, nrow = 20, ncol = 100, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = NULL)
for(j in 1:100) 
for(i in 1:20)
m<-median(myMatrix[ ,j])
```

The result that m spews out is 1050, and I'm now understanding where that's from.

I'm not quite sure how to write a while loop for this but here's what I think it is:

```
C=c(1:2000)
myMatrix1<-matrix(data=C, nrow=20, ncol=100, byrow=TRUE, dimnames=NULL)
m<-rep(0,100)
while (j <= 100)
m[j]<-median(myMatrix1[ , j])
```

I'm not sure why, but it keeps returning C=c(1:2000) for some reason.  Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: For loops are generally not the answer in R. Look into the apply family.

Comment: what's your expected output? a vector of medians where every element is the median per row?

Comment: @erasmortg good question.  I am assuming the median of each column is wanted given `[, j]` in `median(myMatrix1[ , j])`

Answer (score 1):

1050 is simply the median of the last column:

```
median(myMatrix1[,100])
# 1050
```

Your `for` loop should be:

```
D=c(1:2000)
myMatrix1 <- matrix(data = D, nrow = 20, ncol = 100, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = NULL)
m <- rep(0,100)
for(j in 1:100) 
    m[j] <- median( myMatrix1[, j] )
```

There is no need for the `for(i in 1:20)`.

FWIW, you can also use `apply` (I know the point of your exercise is to learn loops).  `apply` is much simpler.

```
 D=c(1:2000)
 myMatrix1 <- matrix(data = D, nrow = 20, ncol = 100, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = NULL)
 result <- apply(myMatrix1, 2, median)
```

[EDIT:  since you have now added an attempt at a while loop.]  You need to increment your counter.

```
C <- c(1:2000)
myMatrix1 <- matrix(data=C, nrow=20, ncol=100, byrow=TRUE, dimnames=NULL)
result2 <- rep(0,100)
j <- 1
while (j <= 100) {
  result2[j]<-median(myMatrix1[ , j])
  j <- j + 1
}
```

I am assuming you are trying to get a vector which contains the median of each column.

Checking all methods are equal [EDIT: using `identical()` instead of summing over the difference of two vectors]

```
identical(m, result1)
## TRUE

identical(result1, result2)
## TRUE
```

Comment: Use `identical()` or `all.equal()` to test equality.

Comment: Instead of the identical command, can you instead use class(m)==class(result1)?

Comment: I am using `identical()` to check if the vectors are equal---so you can see the `for`, `while`, and `apply` approaches return the same answer.

`class()` returns the class of the object, and of course can't be used to check equality of vectors.  In other words `class(1) == class(2)` is `TRUE`.